# Autoscroll from source for "Maven Projects" view in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I'm a pretty experienced `Eclipse` user, and just moved to `IntelliJ Idea` (or at least, trying to).

In `Eclipse` I'm used to "*Link with Editor*" feature of Projects view. I've just found out that the similar feature in `Idea` is called "*Autoscroll from source*" (a bit vague, but OK). It highlights the currently opened file in the "Project" view.

Our project consists of approximately 30 Maven modules, so I'd like to find out, whether there is the same option for "Maven Projects" view. I checked the Maven options, but couldn't find anything like that.

**EDIT**

to see what I mean, take a look at this screenshot:

[image]

**Project** view is successfully synchronized, when I edit pom.xml of *ws-consumer* project, but the selection in **Maven Projects** still highlights the pom.xml of previous project.

Comment: From my point of view, if you have maven project in intelliJ - then it will have the same project structure as maven (with modules). What will be different for you?

Comment: I'm sure that there is no such feature. Write a feature request - intelliJ team surely will look at your proposal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe there's no such feature. You can create a new Enhancement Request [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com).

You can jump to the relevant project manually using `Select Target` feature - <kbd>Alt F1</kbd> and then `Maven Projects`.